# Is safe to insert 'dispatch' function as a dependency in useEffect function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

If I use this

```
  useEffect(() => {
dispatch(fetchToDos())}, [debouncedToDo, loginInfo.isLogin])
```

I get this warning

> React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'dispatch'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

If I include 'dispatch' in dependency array  the warning is gone.

Like this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
dispatch(fetchToDos())}, [dispatch, debouncedToDo, loginInfo.isLogin])
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, `dispatch` is safe to add to an `useEffect` hook's dependency array.

From the [docs](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#usedispatch)

> **INFO**
>
> The `dispatch` function reference will be stable as long as the same store instance is being passed to the `<Provider>`. Normally,
> that store instance never changes in an application.
>
> However, the React hooks lint rules do not know that `dispatch` should
> be stable, and will warn that the `dispatch` variable should be added
> to dependency arrays for `useEffect` and `useCallback`. The simplest
> solution is to do just that:
>
> ```
> export const Todos() = () => {
>   const dispatch = useDispatch();
>
>   useEffect(() => {
>     dispatch(fetchTodos())
>   // Safe to add dispatch to the dependencies array
>   }, [dispatch])
> }
> ```