# The useEffect is not being triggered, even though the dependency is changing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux

I am using react with redux. Using redux to make api calls and state management.
The useEffect in Home component is not being triggered even though the dependency "user" and "dispatch" are changing

I tried with an empty dependency and still the useEffect is not triggering. I have checked that the "user" variable is being assigned the value by the "selectLoggedInUserToken". Also the Home component is being mounted

Home.jsx code:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import Navbar from "../features/Navbar/Navbar";
import ProductList from "../features/product/components/ProductList";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { selectLoggedInUserToken } from "../features/auth/authSlice";
import { fetchItemsByUserIdAsync } from "../features/cart/cartSlice";
import { fetchLoggedInUserAsync } from "../features/user/userSlice";

const Home = () => {
  const user = useSelector(selectLoggedInUserToken);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("In use efffect");
    if (user) {
      console.log("In if condition of useEffect");
      dispatch(fetchItemsByUserIdAsync());
      dispatch(fetchLoggedInUserAsync());
    }
  }, [user, dispatch]);

  return (
    <Navbar>
      <ProductList></ProductList>
    </Navbar>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Comment: why are you adding dispatch as a dependency? and is your user is getting a value from the state?

Comment: @SakshiMahajan `dispatch` is added as a dependency because it is referenced in the effect and is an external reference.

Comment: I don't see any overt issue with this code. It sounds like you are saying the `useEffect` hook isn't running at all. How is `Home` being rendered? Please [edit] to provide better details, reproduction steps, and a complete [mcve].

Comment: you should try logging `user` value above useEffect

Comment: @SakshiMahajan `dispatch` doesn't change, it's a false positive from TS/Eslint. [More here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67012349/2891356)

Comment: It's clear that `user` doesn't change here. What does `selectLoggedInUserToken` look like and also show how you are setting `user` to state.

Answer (score -3):

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("In use effect");
  console.log("user:", user);
  console.log("dispatch:", dispatch);
    
  if (user) {
    console.log("In if condition of useEffect");
    dispatch(fetchItemsByUserIdAsync());
    dispatch(fetchLoggedInUserAsync());
  }
}, [user, dispatch]);
```

Comment: Try providing an explanation as to what issue the OP is facing and how you solved it. Your code seems to only add print statements to OP's code, this won't solve the issue. If this is an attempt of asking the OP for debugging, a comment would be a better place